# If an average of a particle goes to 0, and the particle can't move arbitrarily fast, does the particle converge to something?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Suppose I have a vector  that is moving, $v(t)\in \mathbb R^n$. I want to show that the following 3 properties must contradict, but I can't show it.

- $D_1 \leq \|v(t)\|_2 \leq D_2$ and $D_1$, $D_2$ are both big (but constant) numbers.
- $\|v'(t)\|_2 = O(1/t)$ ($v$ slows down at a rate of $O(1/t)$)
- $\|\int_t^\infty \frac{1}{\tau} v(\tau) d\tau\| = O(1/t)$ (the decaying average of $v$ decays to 0.)

Somehow the last property suggests that $v(t)$ orbits around 0. The second property says $v(t)$'s orbit speed can't be too big, but the first says the orbit "width" can be arbitrarily big.

Any ideas as to what theorems / lemmas I could start looking at to show this? In my head it makes perfect sense that this trifecta can't happen, but no idea of how to prove it!

Also, an upper bound on $D_1$ would also be useful! But I actually think $\|v(t)\|_2\to 0$ necessarily...

Edit: slightly modified condition 1. $v(t)$ is bounded, can be very big, but can't grow.

Edit 2: Ok, I think I can do a proof, but I need something like this to be true:

If $f(t) = O(1/t^p)$ for some $p > 0$, then $-f'(t) \leq O(1/t^{p+1})$.

Basically, even though inequalities don't usually carry over via differentiation, if we assume asymptotic then some property *should* carry over. Again, totally makes sense in my head, no idea what theorem to cite.

Comment: Do you mean $O(1/t)$?

Comment: yes, will change it

Comment: Unless I am missing something: When $v'(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ in $\mathbb R$ then $v(t)=\log t$ which can get arbitrarily big. The extension to a straight motion along any coordinate axis in $\mathbb R^n$ is trivial.

Comment: yes, but then the third condition doesn't work, since $\int_t^\infty \log(\tau)/\tau d\tau$ diverges

Comment: In 1 d, I believe the third condition requires $v(t)$ to be alternating around 0. But even then, there's no constraint on periodicity or anything. Is there a counterexample I'm missing?

Comment: This isn't a counterexample, but $v(t) = \bigl( \cos(\log t), \sin(\log t) \bigr)$ comes close: the integral in the third bullet point doesn't converge, but the corresponding integral from $t$ to $e^{2\pi}t$ equals $0$ exactly! It's just that in the middle of these periods, the integral gets up to $O(1)$ in size.

Comment: Interesting. I think I need to rephrase it to really say that stuff has to happen asymptotically, so that in the middle of the periods the integral does have to converge. But this is useful because it helps me figure out how the conditions need to be phrased. thanks!